# Could the combobox.removeAllItems method throw an exception if the combobox was empty?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

The documentation doesn't specify this case. It seems that nothing happens, but I am not sure. Could this method throw an exception eventually?

Comment: follow the JavaDoc or try it yourself by creating a simple program.

Comment: or find it in [Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JComboBox.java#JComboBox.removeAllItems%28%29). what do you think? Will it throw any exception. I don't think so.

Comment: are you testing us?or you want to learn ? you should try the code first if you really want to learn :) then SO is here to answer all your questions :)

Comment: In general, if the documentation does not say it *can/will* throw an exception, then it will not throw an exception.

Comment: 1) The answer is "most likely not", 2) but the only way to know the definitive answer to this is for you to look at first the API, 2) and if it is not stated there, then look at the source code. 3) Best not to bite hands that have fed you in the past or might feed you in the future. If you don't like a comment (like this one), then just ignore it rather than make a personal attack on the author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick test reveals that nothing happens:

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;    

class ComboBoxTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<String>();
        box.removeAllItems();
    }
}
```

No errors were thrown